Is it possible to configure location on desktop where screenshots are saved in macOS?
I take screenshots that I mainly use to send to co-workers in Slack. Screenshots are automatically saved to the desktop.
I tend to move the icon to the bottom corner of the screen so I can drag them into Slack, which I have open maximized most of the time.
Is there a way to configure where exactly the screenshot icons will populate visually on the desktop screen?

One way would be to set the order in which icons are displayed, e.g., by Kind, https://www.ias.edu/itg/content/arranging-icons-mac-desktop Then all images would be together.

I think it would be simpler to change the location to be a folder instead of the Desktop.
